# While loop does not stop when the condition is met

Tags: python, string, while-loop, formatting, break

I want to stop this while loop when it prints "You smell funny Trump!". The code does stop, but it does not stop at the right sentence, what did I do wrong here?

```
while True:

  from time import sleep
  from random import randint

  greetings = ["Hello","Howdy","You smell funny"]
  title = ["Human.", "Trump!" , "Maid."]
  greeting = "{x}, {y}".format(x=greetings[randint(0,2)], y=title[randint(0,2)])

  if greeting == "{x}, {y}".format(x=greetings[2], y=title[1]):
    break
  else:
    sleep(0.3)
    print(greeting)
```

Comment: Indent your code properly and people will be more able to help. Either way the problem is that you never print the greeting once it meets your criteria. The break statement exits the while-loop and `print(greeting)` never gets executed.

Comment: You might want to do the imports outside your loop as well.

Comment: @JimNilsson, thank you for the reminder, now I indented them properly. 
and I now see the problem, so it looks like I just add one line, print the greeting above "if" will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have printed the "greeting" yet, when it hits the `break` and stops the loop. Just move the `print(greeting)`  to just before the `if greeting == ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a Flag instead of 'break' to exit loop.

```
Break_Flag=True
while Break_Flag:
    from time import sleep
    from random import randint
    greetings = ["Hello","Howdy","You smell funny"]
    title = ["Human.", "Trump!" , "Maid."]
    greeting = "{x}, {y}".format(x=greetings[randint(0,2)], y=title[randint(0,2)])
    if greeting == "{x}, {y}".format(x=greetings[2], y=title[1]):
        print(greeting,"Stop")  
        Break_Flag=False
    else:
        sleep(0.3)
        print(greeting)
```

Comment: How to insert Python Code, my code looks disordered.

Comment: before every line of code, enter 4 spaces. I edited this one for you and it awaits review.

Comment: Thank you so much. Another Q, If I copy the code from PyCharm and each lines still need be insert 4 spaces?

Comment: I don't know out of my head, but every time you are writing an answer here, you can see the preview of your answer further below. If it doesn't show like this, as a code, then add 4 spaces.